# Laravel Job calling repository falling in exceeded time

Tags: laravel, jobs

I've a job which uses a repository

```
    public function handle()
    {
...
// all dd() i use here are OK, no exceeded time
...
    $annuaireRepository = new AnnuaireRepository();
        $liste = $annuaireRepository->find('vcard', '', 0, '', '', '', '');
// dd() not displaying, exceeded time
...
}
```

And the repository

```
    public function find($requete, $type, $champ1, $champ2, $total, $page_courante, $nombre_resultat_page)
...
// all dd() i use here are OK, no exceeded time
...
        DB::connection('sqlsrv_database')
                    ->raw("SET NOCOUNT ON;");
        $queryDatas = DB::connection('sqlsrv_database')
...
// all dd() i use here are OK, no exceeded time
...
            ->select($select)
            ;
// dd() not displaying, exceeded time

        return collect($queryDatas);
    }
```

The exceeded time occurs with the
`->select($select)`
in the repository

But it happens only with the job.

I use the repository in another controller and all is fine.

Some idea ?

---

One day later, i found the source of the problem.

I have a Windows IIS server and I connect to a sqlserver database with an ODBC driver.

I have set up ODBC traces.

Job + active trace: 10 minutes and the log file is filling up

Job + inactive trace: immediate

Controller + active trace: immediate and the log file does not fill up

Controller + inactive trace: immediate

There should be logs for controller + trace, right?

Or on the contrary, there shouldn't be any for job + trace?

Is the problem on the Laravel side or on the ODBC trace side?

Answer (score 0):

I permanently disabled the trace.

The behavior is still surprising.